# How to set a button property for multiple buttons using foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 12 buttons in ASP.NET page. I want to color the button; But My code is not work. I will check with break point but   button.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen; code is not executed.

**ASP Design Coding -**

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server" style="background-color:Silver; height:100%; min-height:300px">   
       <div style="height:100%;">
            <div style="height:20%;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>    
        </div>
        <div id="content" runat="server" class="content" style="height:70%; min-height:180px">    
            <div >               
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False"/>               
                <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="UP" onclick="btnUp_Click" style="width:32%" /> <br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" /> <br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" /> <br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
                    Enabled="False" />            
                <asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="DOWN" onclick="btnDown_Click" style="width:32%" /> <br /><br />
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->        
        </div>       
          <div id="footer" class="footer" style="height:10%;">
             <a href="OutLet.aspx" >Home</a>
             <a href="Selection.aspx">Selection</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

***C# Coding - ***

```
var buttons = this.form1.Controls.OfType<Button>();
        foreach (var button in buttons)
        {
           button.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
        }
```

Comment: is there any need to the set the background color in the code? you can set color as a style anyway in the aspx page

Comment: @Jayanga I want to change the button Color via Code, Bz,.. Its shows the Status like Green is vacant and red is occupied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace one of your divs with an ASP.NET Panel(which is rendered as div but can be referenced from codebehind):

```
<asp:Panel id="ButtonPanel" runat="server">               
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False"/>               
    <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="UP" onclick="btnUp_Click" style="width:32%" /> <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" /> <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" /> <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" style="width:32%" 
        Enabled="False" />            
    <asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="DOWN" onclick="btnDown_Click" style="width:32%" /> <br /><br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then you can loop all controls in this panel, take every button and do what you need to do:

```
foreach(Control c in ButtonPanel.Controls){
    if(c.GetType()==typeof(Button)){
        Button btn = (Button)c;
        btn.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** as mentioned by @Abbas, if using at least .NET framework 3.5 you can use the [Enumerable.OfType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx#Y0):

```
foreach(Button btn in ButtonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
        btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
}
```

Comment: Or without the if: foreach(var button in buttonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>()) { //color the button }

Comment: `GetType()` with `typeof()` and a cast? Why not use `as`? `Button btn = c as Button; if (btn != null) { btn.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen; }`

Comment: Possible, but then you'd have to check the type manually (as you mentioned) but if you'd forget you get exceptions. With OfType<Button> you're automatically sure you'll only get the buttons.

Comment: There was no need to change the div to a panel.  You can access child controls in code-behind for a div that has runat="server".

Comment: @varangian: Not necessary, but it's clearer and provides more control in codebehind. In general, if i need to access controls on serverside i'm using their serverside counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the problem here is that the Controls property will only give you direct child controls of form1.  To get your buttons, use:

```
var buttons = this.content.Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

However I would also agree with Jayanga, CSS would do the job better.

Answer (score 0):

The controls collection only contains immediate children. My guess is that `var buttons` has zero items in it.

```
foreach( Control c in this.[immediate parent ID].Controls )
{
    Button b = c as Button;
    if( b != null )
    {
        b.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    }
}
```

As @Jayanga's comment points out, you can (and should) set the styles of the buttons using CSS in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from any need to specifically use codebehind for setting background color of your buttons, I recommend you to use javascript to achieve this as it is really fast. [Eample here](http://jsfiddle.net/FmfdH/4/)